# Having trouble finding complex roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How could I find all of the complex roots to $a^{1001} = 1$? I assume it’s using Euler’s formula??

Comment: Look up "roots of unity" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Put $$a=\rho e^{i\theta}$$

then

$$a^{1001}=\rho^{1001}e^{1001 i\theta}=1=1\cdot e^{i2k\pi}$$
by identification,

$$\rho=1$$
and
$$1001 \cdot \theta=2k\pi$$

You can take it now.

Comment: So then would each root be equal to $e^{/frac{kπi}{1010}}$?